# Treeview adding duplicate nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a tree of a depth of 2 as follows.

```
Module 1
    Form 1
         Tab 1
    Form 2
         Tab 2
         Tab 3
    Form 2
         Tab 2
         Tab 3
Module 2
    Form 4
         Tab 2
    Form 5
         Tab 4
         Tab 5
         Tab 6
    Form 5
         Tab 4
         Tab 5
         Tab 6
    Form 5
         Tab 4
         Tab 5
         Tab 6
```

As shown above, the problem is that, the `Forms` will be displayed as many times as the `Tabs` they have. For example, if `Form 5` has **three** `Tabs`, it will be displayed thrice. 
I need them to be displayed just once since their tabs are the same.

This is my code:

```
private void LoadTreeview()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT Module, Form, Tab, HelpText " +
                        "FROM PageHelp " +
                        "WHERE Module IS NOT NULL";
        DataTable dt = Public_Methods.Get_DataTable(sql);

        DataView dvModules = new DataView(dt, "Module IS NOT NULL", "Module ASC", DataViewRowState.Unchanged);
        DataTable dtModules = dvModules.ToTable(true, "Module");

        for (int count = 0; count < dtModules.Rows.Count; count++)
        {
            TreeNode TModule = new TreeNode();
            TModule.Value = dtModules.Rows[count]["Module"].ToString();
            TModule.Text = dtModules.Rows[count]["Module"].ToString();
            TModule.Collapse();

            LoadForms(ref TModule, dt);
            TreeView_EditHelp_Help.Nodes.Add(TModule);                
        }
    }

    private void LoadForms(ref TreeNode TModule, DataTable dt)
    {
        DataRow[] drForms = dt.Select("Module='" + TModule.Value + "'");

        for (int count = 0; count < drForms.Length; count++)
        {
            TreeNode TForm = new TreeNode();
            TForm.Value = drForms[count]["Form"].ToString();
            TForm.Text = drForms[count]["Form"].ToString();
            TForm.Collapse();

            LoadTabs(ref TForm, dt);
            TModule.ChildNodes.Add(TForm);
        }
    }

    private void LoadTabs(ref TreeNode TForm, DataTable dt)
    {
        DataRow[] drTabs = dt.Select("Form='" + TForm.Value + "'");
        for (int count = 0; count < drTabs.Length; count++)
        {
            TreeNode TTab = new TreeNode();
            TTab.Value = drTabs[count]["Tab"].ToString();
            TTab.Text = drTabs[count]["Tab"].ToString();
            TTab.Collapse();
            TForm.ChildNodes.Add(TTab);
        }
    }
```

Any assistance please?

Comment: Your SQL query returns a list of rows of the shape `(module, form, tab)`, so if you have 3 tabs belonging to the same module and form, those are present in all 3 rows. Still, you handle the modules properly. Just do the same for the forms.

Comment: How many records does `DataRow[] drForms = dt.Select("Module='" + TModule.Value + "'");` brings back? That's where your problem is. I suggest you filter distinct on these.

Comment: @Heuster thats true, i don't have issues with the `Modules` for they display well, only the `Forms` have a problem. Have tried that but there arises a problem of selecting a field which doesn't belong to the table in the method.

Comment: @SollyM it returns the first `Form` of the `Module`. Actually i think my problem is in the `LoadForm()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataRow[] drForms = dt.Select("Module='" + TModule.Value + "'");
```

change to:

```
DataRow[] drForms = dt.Select("Module='" + TModule.Value + "'").CopyToDataTable().DefaultView.ToTable(true,"Form").Select();
```

Comment: Works like magic. You should have joined stackoverflow ages ago. 
Spent like 5 hours debugging this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try with some thing like below

```
for (int count = 0; count < dtModules.Rows.Count; count++)
        {
            TreeNode TModule = new TreeNode();
            TModule.Value = dtModules.Rows[count]["Module"].ToString();
            TModule.Text = dtModules.Rows[count]["Module"].ToString();
            TModule.Collapse();
f =0;
             for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
{  // check the new module has been previously ocured or not
 if(dtModules.Rows[count]["Module"].ToString() == dtModules.Rows[j]["Module"].ToString())
  {  
 f=1;
break;
}
}

 if(f== 0){
            LoadForms(ref TModule, dt);
            TreeView_EditHelp_Help.Nodes.Add(TModule);                
}
        }
```

you can create separate function for checking  as well

Comment: Haven't tried this but the answer above solved my problem with just one line of code.

Comment: the problem in your code was it was fetching records for same module as many times it occur, i have just checked that if if has been previously occurred, don't go for it